# Characterise the continuous functions from the co-countable to the usual topology on R

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I have been following the topology lecture notes [here](http://www.math.toronto.edu/ivan/mat327/?resources) but I am struggling with the following question

> Characterize the continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}_{co-countable}$ to $\mathbb{R}_{usual}.$

It is my first time doing a 'characterise' type question. I was thinking along these lines

> Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function with respect to the above topologies.
> Suppose that $U\in\mathcal{T}_{usual}$ and that $f^{-1}(U)\in\mathcal{T}_{co-countable}$.
> Then, $\mathbb{R}\setminus f^{-1}(U)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\ |\ f(x)\not\in U\}$ is countable.

I stared at these three lines of my paper but haven't the faintest idea of what to do next. Any hints or guidance is appreciated!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: First two small but important points about your three lines: * I would change "and that" in the second line to "so that" (the assertion about $f^{-1}(U)$ is a deduction, not an assumption). * The conclusion should be that the set in the third line is countable or all of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Now for strategic comments: doing mathematics involves having two processes going in our brains at the same time: articulating the formal structure of the proof, and brainstorming and forming intuition about what the truth is. You've done a great job so far with the first process! Try playing around with examples of simple functions and see whether they are continuous or not (linear functions for example?). I think you're at the step when you need to know what you're trying to prove about $f$ before you can actually finish the proof. (Hint: consider $U=(-\frac1n,\frac1n)$ for $n=1,2,\dots$.)

Comment: For a slightly simpler example where the brainstorming/gaining intuition is concerned, try characterizing the continuous functions from $\Bbb R_{usual}$ to $\Bbb R_{discrete\ topology}$. And vice versa. And same with $\Bbb R_{indiscrete\ topolgy}$.

Comment: Hint: The preimages of disjoint open sets under a continuous function are disjoint open sets.

Comment: Thank you lots @GregMartin for the general guidance and encouragement - it's really helpful as I want to become a bit more confident with the area and not just this question in particular.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelGreinecker for the hint!